# problemin adding index field to linq results

Tags: c#, linq

I need sequence numbering for my records display. 50 record for each page.

```
    public List<string[]> InstructionsData(IEnumerable<Assets> InstructionsEntry, int currentUserId)
    {

        return InstructionsEntry.Select((entry,index) => new string[]
        {                  
           (index + 1).ToString(),
            entry.state_Id,                
            entry.batchRef_Id,
            entry.assetCategory_Id,                
            GetAge(entry.age),                
            entry.assetStatus_Id,
            GetStatusTag(entry.recordStatus ??false),
            entry.availbaleQty.ToString(),
            entry.createdBy,

        }).ToList();
```

The above code which is used for displaying index is working fine. My problem is when I move to next page the index again start from first. Please help me to continue the index number on next page as well.

Comment: You will have to use the linq skip and take commands, but your function is structured wrong as it does not take an index for pagination. Try to reformat your question and method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple :

```
public List<string[]> InstructionsData(IEnumerable<Assets> InstructionsEntry, int currentUserId, int startIndex)
    {

        return InstructionsEntry.Select((entry,index) => new string[]
        {                  
           (startIndex + index + 1).ToString(),
            entry.state_Id,                
            entry.batchRef_Id,
            entry.assetCategory_Id,                
            GetAge(entry.age),                
            entry.assetStatus_Id,
            GetStatusTag(entry.recordStatus ??false),
            entry.availbaleQty.ToString(),
            entry.createdBy,

        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I will not argue about your design choices like

- why do you need to return an array of strings instead of structured object?
- or why do you need the index when you must have a unique identifier to rely on?

you might have your very peculiar specific reasons behind the scenes, but I'll try to pin point what i might end up doing to retrieve a paginated indexed result set.

First thing first, get a paginated result set of assets (or whatever your use case scenario requires), having some metadata about the given page (current page number, page size, total records)

```
var paged = data.Page(page: 2, size: 5);
```

Then on the frontend, or wherever the result is to be displayed, attach the index to returned records (I'll show the C# equivalent, but you will easily achieve the same results in your frontend of choice tech stack)

```
var indexed = paged.Items
    .Select((current, index) =>
    {
        var skipped = (paged.Page - 1) * paged.Size;
        return new
        {
            Index = skipped + index,
            Item = current,
        };
    });
```

where the paged result would look like this

```
public class Paged<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; set; }
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}

public class Asset
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

while the actual paging mechanism simply applies `Skip` and `Take`

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static Paged<T> Page<T>(this IEnumerable<T> instance, int? page = 1, int? size = 10)
    {
        var items = instance
            .Skip((page.Value - 1) * size.Value)
            .Take(size.Value)
            .ToList();

        return new Paged<T>()
        {
            Page = page.Value,
            Size = size.Value,
            Total = instance.Count() - 1,
            Items = items,
        };
    }
}
```

check [gist](https://gist.github.com/dandohotaru/1d9c20091653b88c8ee14a1da6fef517#file-stack-48459247-cs) for an overview code sample